# Setting Content-Encoding Response header via WebLogic

Tags: http-headers, weblogic

I have a web application where part of its job is to serve out zipped binary files that are included within the war.  The Web App is deployed to WebLogic.

The client application is Javascript based and is requesting the zipped files.  Since, WebLogic is not currently setting the Content-Encoding: Zip in the Http Response header for the GET of the file, the web browser does not know it is a compressed file so it can't handle it correctly.

I need a way to set the Content-Encoding header to gzip within WebLogic when one of these files is requested.  I have worked around it by hosting the files via Apache and adding an
    AddEncoding x-gzip .

Any ideas on how to do the equivalent thing via WebLogic?

Comment: That is rather confusing. Could you clarify the question? Is it a webservice application that is serving those zipped binaries? Which protocol is used? SOAP/JAXWS?

Comment: @AlesJ I clarified the orignail text of the question.

Comment: From what I remember from older versions of WebLogic, the "right" way to do it was creating a filter which would do the dirty job for you. Something like you can see [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4183753).